# Union all and Selection

Tags: sql

Suppose that there is a  table  `action`  that keeps track whether a feature is on or off. The fields are  `user_id` , `status`  ("on" or "off),  `date`  and  `time` .

Additionally, there is a table  `user_status`  that keeps historical data about users. The fields are  `user_id` , `status` ,  `date`  and  `time` .

**Question**. How many users turned the feature on today? How many users have ever turned the feature on? How do you add the current data to the historical data?

One answer that is given is the following:

```
select count(distinct(user_id)) from action
where status = "on" and date = today()
```

But it seems that this would also include people who already had their status as "on" the previous day.

Another answer that is given is:

```
create table total as
 ( select us.user_id, today(), us.status
    from
    (select user_id, status, date 
     from user_status 
     where date = today()-1) us

    left outer join

    (select user_id, status, date, max(time)
     from action
     where date = today()
     group by user_id, status) ts on us.user_id = ts.user_id
     where ts.user_id is null

    union all

    select user_id, today(), status
    from
    (select user_id,status, max(time)
    from action
    where date = today()
    group by user_id, status) a

    union all

    select * from user_status )
```

This seems to account for both the users who had the same status as yesterday  and users who had different actions from yesterday? Would this basically add today's data to the historical data? Then you could answer the first two questions as follows:

```
select count(distinct(user_id)) from total
where status = "on" and date = today()

select count(distinct(user_id)) from total
where status = "on"
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: can you please add expected output,table data as text

Comment: @TheGameiswar: None was provided. It was an interview question.

Comment: look out this link on more info on how to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: No offense, but if this is an interview question, shouldn't you be doing this on your own? Why should we help you get a job?

Comment: @virusstorm Why not?

Comment: @virusstorm: It is a past interview question that I am going through. I am just trying to compare different solutions.

Comment: What's the trigger to INSERT into the user_status table? In other words, the user_status table may or may not already contain the current data from the action table (along with prior changes to the action table).

Answer (score 0):

```
select
count(distinct (case when status="on" and date=today() then user_id else null end)) as current,
count(distinct (case when status="on" and date<today() then user_id else null end)) as previous
from action
```